# How to debug a TLS implementation

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox, ssl, openssl

I am writing a TLS implementation and have been stuck at the server finished message for weeks now. Openssl s_client give sthe error:

> 5820:error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or
>   bad record mac:.\ssl \s3_pkt.c:483:

which is not very helpful because I cannot trace anything wrong to the MAC or the encryption process.
Chrome gives the error:

> 5820:error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or
>   bad record mac:.\ssl \s3_pkt.c:483:

while Firefox says:

> Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption
>   algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

GNUtls-debug is even worse

> error in the pull function.

I have narrowed down the suspect list to either a wrong des3/aes256 implementation(the only ones I've tried so far) or bad MAC, but I cannot be sure, and have been over the code for what feels like a thousand times with no luck of spotting anything evil going on.
**Questions**
Is there any way to get any browser to give a full and detailed SSL error? All I need is a detailed and reliable error message/debug log. 
Are there any tools for debugging a TLS implementation?

Comment: I don't think there's much demand for low-level TLS protocol tools because there aren't that many people implementing TLS. I would build the `openssl` executable with debug enabled, run `s_client` in a debugger, and set a breakpoint on every `decryption_failed_or_bad_record_mac = 1` in `ssl3_get_record()`. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will do some SSL/TLS parsing but my guess is not at the depth you want. Is your server on the internet?

Comment: My server is currently not online. I shall build openssl with debug enabled.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I wrote a TLS 1.0/1.1 proxy awhile ago and struggled with this step for a long time.  I ended up doing a packet capture of my transaction and then computing by hand what all the values should be.  It took a long time, but by logging all relevant values in my code I could then compute by hand where I went wrong.  Some issues I struggled with:

Comment: ...<continued> Some issues I struggled with: correctly capturing all the handshake messages (but not Change Cipher Spec messages), getting the right encryption key and MAC secret from the keying material, calling the crypto libraries correctly for encryption and MAC functions, and using the decrypted Finished message from the client in computing the Finished message from the server.  Maybe something here will trigger an idea that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same boat, updating an embedded TLS 1.0 implementation to TLS 1.2.  I've found that Wireshark is great for troubleshooting as I go.

Go into the Wireshark Preferences to Protocols/SSL.  From the RSA keys list you can give it a path to the private key (in my case, a .pem file) you're using on your server.  Configure Wireshark with an SSL debug file, and it will dump extended debug information for each packet it decrypts.

Right now, I see that my AES256 decryption is broken since Wireshark decodes differently than my implementation.  Earlier, I was getting the proper cleartext on an AES128 connection and had to work out some problems with my MAC calculations (or the finished messages, can't recall which).  Without Wireshark, it was difficult to know whether the decryption or MAC steps had failed.

Answer (score 1):

tcpdump the all connection first, and make sure you haven't miss some protocols such as handshake, Change Cipher Spec and so on, and then open the firfox debug option and gdb the firefox to print the masterkey, and the 6 key pairs, and print in your own implementation these things, and then you may find the answer.